# jQuery - enable "display errors" in console

Tags: jquery

Whenever We have :

```
$("something")
```

it doesnt shows any errors in console, if it cant find element with that tag. Is there a way, to show errors/notices, if it cant get element (like Plain Javascript does it with `getElementBy...`, when element doesnt exist .. )

**EDIT 1**:
some people say, that it is not error, it is just "not found".. and i  disagree with this opinion,because then all world should report BROWSERS (google, FF, Opera) that they make mistake. Why? because they do **show** in console (and they do great job!) when element is not found (with `getElementBy..`). And i want that jQuery did the same. How to enable that feature?

**EDIT 2**: I dont want manual checking everytime (`$(element).length` or etc), i want to enable ERROR debugger (not conditional coding and etc)..

**EDIT 3**: How about that we reported jQuery, to give us ability to define i.e. `jQuery_Enable_Notices = true;` (or smth like this) variable, and in that case, jQuery functions showd console log for such errors?

Comment: But this is not an error. It is just not found. You can create errors by your own like `if( !$("something").length )`.

Comment: You can disagree as mutch as you like. ;) But we should be happy that jQuery don't throw errors when nothing was found by a selector. This is very wanted, because of this you can use jQuery as you know it. If there would be an error whenever an selector returnd no elements, it would not work. There are often situations where you select something on *good luck*, like `$('.active')` of `$(':checked')` whenever there isn't something active or selected yet.

Comment: _“(like Plain Javascript does it with getElementBy..., when element doesnt exist .. )”_ – document.getElementById('foo') does not throw an error either, it just returns null if the element can not be found. Your code that _follows_ that might throw errors of course, if it tries to access properties or call methods on null afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

By default for jQuery it is not an error, it is a wanted behavior.

The only way I would know, is to build yourself a wrapper around the jQuery constructor. Then you would be able to print errors by yourself, whenever no elements was not found by a selector.

But this is really a workaround for your needs! I would only use this for development purpose and not in a productive environment. And note, this will not work for sub-selectors like `find`, `children`, `next` and others, only for the base construct. Otherwise you have to wrap all of them. ;)

```js
$ = function(selector, context) {
    var elements = jQuery(selector, context);

    if( !elements.length ) {
        console.log("element(s) by selector '" + selector + "' was not found");
    }

    return elements;
}

$("div").text("test");
$("something").text("test");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 if( $('selector').length )         // use this if you are using id to check
{
     // it exists
}

else
{
console.log("not exist")
}
```

use `$('#selector').length` it give you length if tag is exist otherwise else condition run

you can also use like this

```
// if element does not exist

    if(!$('selector').length){ /* console here   */ }
```

Comment: yes, and that's what i requested, i didnt know that code myself.

Answer (score -1):

try this one:

```
if ($("#mydiv").length > 0){
  // do something here
}
```

this will return zero if element does not exists.